# Outlook 2013 Read messages disappear from view

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I am in a search and I mark the message read, or even if I begin to reply to the message, it disappears from view and doesn't allow for the reply.

The only way to see it again is to get out of the search.

Comment: Where exactly are you performing the search. Is it inside some "[Search Folder](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-a-search-folder-HA102749458.aspx)"?

Comment: I'm searching within outlook in the search current folder field.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not specify the search criteria.

Remove "unread" from criteria.

Comment: OMG .. .  when I did this. . . every single unread message in the folder I was in started to disappear.